# MATLAB parfor error

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have a Matlab function in which I use parfor and it goes like this:

```
sbestposition=zeros(8,38);
sbestvalue=zeros(8,1);

matlabpool open 8
parfor i=1:8
    [ sbestvalue(i) sbestposition(i,1:i+30)] = pso(lb, ub, s2, i+31, 30,1,2,2 );
end
matlabpool close
```

The sizeof `sbestposition` depends of the value of `i` and it is `(1,31)` when `i=1` and `(1,38)` when `i=8`; and I intend to keep their values in one variable.

The function works when it is `[ sbestvalue(i) sbestposition(i,:)] = pso(lb, ub, s2, i+31, 30,1,2,2 );` But when I use it, the function will not work again because of the dimension mismatch error.

Instead, here it gives an error

> The variable sbestposition in a parfor cannot be classified

How do I overcome this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a cell array for sbestposition

```
parfor i = 1:8
    [sbestvalue(i), sbestposition{i}] = ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does not "know" how to slice a variable in such a complex pattern. Every iteration uses at most the full row, most less that the row. Make it obvious that the variable should be sliced row wise:

```
parfor i=1:8
    p=zeros(1,38);
    [sbestvalue(i),p(1:i+30)]=pso(lb, ub, s2, i+31, 30,1,2,2 );
    sbestposition(i,:)=p;
end
```

In this code, the toolbox can push each row to one worker, having obviously no interference.

Comment: I agree with Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the dimension of the variable inside the **parloop**.

Comment: I don't see any dimension change.

Comment: all the variables that are going to be changed, should be defined inside the loop.

Comment: Except sliced variables: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_tcng-1

Comment: There are no dimension changes, the dimensions are predefined. However, in order to avoid the dimension mismatch, I tried to come up with that solution. However, the part @DanielR has sent opened up my mind a little more. I'll keep on trying. Thanks everyone.